# What is the most natural way of expressing where you come from?

Tags: grammaire, oral, interrogative

To ask where someone is from, or to express where you are from, are the following questions phrased correctly and in a common, normal way?

> Je viens des Etats-Unis. Je viens (suis?) de NY. (I am from NY.)
>
> D'où venez-vous ?

Answer (score 4):

***Je viens des États-Unis/de New-York*** is possibly ambiguous. It might just mean you are travelling from the US/from NY. ***Je suis de New-York*** is okay and means you are from New-York city.

I would suggest:

> *— Je suis américain, j'habite New-York.*
>        Spoken (vous): *Et vous, vous êtes d'où ?*
>         Spoken (*tu*): *Et toi, tu es (t'es) d'où ?*
>        Formal: *Et vous, d'où êtes vous (originaire) ?*

Comment: *D'où tu viens ?* , *Tu viens d'où* avec ou sans *Et toi,* devant. Familier.

Comment: @jcm69 J'évite « d'où tu viens » qui peut être parfois mal perçu.

Comment: Omg, you don't need *à* after *habiter*? Christ, the number of times I've said that....nobody ever stopped me.

Comment: @aerovistae *à* is optional here

Comment: @Aerovistae: It perfectly fine. Dropping it sounds a bit literary.

Comment: @jlliagre dans une conversation, une question, "D'où tu viens ?", ne me choque pas forcément... Mais oui ! vous avez entièrement raison « d'où tu viens » peut être utilisé à toutes les sauces et perçu de la même manière.